# Let $f:R\rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism. Prove or disprove: if $f$ is one-to-one and $R$ is a field, then $S$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $f:R\rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism. Prove or disprove: if $f$ is one-to-one and $R$ is a field, then $S$ is a field.

My attempt: I believe this statement is false, as I can imagine a scenario where some element $s\in S$ is not $f(r)$ for some $r\in R$, and this element $s$ is not a unit. However, I'm having trouble coming up with an explicit counterexample.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed any field $k$ into the polynomial ring $k[x]$, but the latter is not a field.

Answer (score 0):

Take a field $K$ and product ring $K\times K$.